# Infiniti G35 2003, how to position window regulator when re-attaching to inside panel?

Tags: infiniti, window, g35

Trying to replace my window motor and regulator. Connected the new parts fine but can't seem to position the regulator correctly, the window fidgets around and every time I try and place the metal panel back on the door, the holes just don't line up, I can only ever get one bolt in. I tried it with the window up, with the window down. It seems like the brackets or whatever don't stay in place they just kind of sit in there free floating without any fixture in the door housing.

Please see this vid for explanation:

https://vimeo.com/230545720

I've tried to mimic the regulator positions I'm seeing here: https://youtu.be/e_sMNdSMbV0?t=170 but I just can't get it.

Is there any indicator in the door housing of where it should be positioned, and how can I get it to not fidget and move once I screw in the motor? Because one of the motor is connected to the panel I have 10 times less slack on the panel and making adjustments is difficult.

Comment: Huh?  Seems an odd way to go.  Place the regulator somewhere in the middle. Slide the glass up / down until the bolts line up.  In fact, when I replace glass, I secure the regulator to sheet metal first, then install the glass (which does involve a bit of up/down trials).  Add the window tracks last.  Do note, every car is different.  What does your Chilton / Haynes repair manual say?  (hint, hint).

Comment: Well I got it working, but it just took a lot of playing with. The bolts that screw the regulator to the window have leeway of position which caused the difficulty, after that you don't really have any play because the bolts of the regulator line up specifically to the inside panel.